# Preview of (Desktop Site) on Mobile browser is not responsive as compared to computer browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, mobile-browser

Here the pictures of the Mobile browser (Desktop Site) and Computer browser at the same width. It is not giving me the same result.

Here the pic that is set to 980px on mobile browser desktop site:
[[image 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHeCN.png)

And here the whole pic of the page on mobile
[[image 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmBg6.png)

And this is the last image on computer browser
[[image 3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agQ3Q.png)

And here it is [hosted check it - click here](https://result-card.000webhostapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width or height in % not by px, another method using css here documentation: [@media method]
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what you want to accomplish. Responsive means that it will look good on all devices, not necessary the same. Even if the resolutions are the same, the mobile screen is smaller.

I can't see you site on that link, maybe you were logged in or something. But it has to do with how `background-size` was handled on `<body>` element, and I assume it is set to `cover`.

You can take a look here and play a bit:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover